# Kubernetes: Haproxy used as tcp loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

I'm trying to setup haproxy as tcp loadbalancer, i have an haproxy installation via helm and i set this in the value file:

```
tcp:
    "26257": "cockroachdb-instance/cockroachdb-public:26257::::-"
```

In the deployment a configmap is correctly provisioned:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: haproxy-ingress-0.14.3
    app.kubernetes.io/name: haproxy-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: helm-chart
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "v0.14.3"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: helm-chart-haproxy-ingress-tcp
  namespace: haproxy
data:
  "26257": "cockroachdb-instance/cockroachdb-public:26257::::-"
```

but when I proceed to get my ingresses in the cluster I don't see the port 26257:

```
k get ingress -A
NAMESPACE              NAME              CLASS     HOSTS                                                     ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
cockroachdb-instance   sql-cockroachdb   haproxy   cockroachdb.dev-service-stage.k8s.mi1.prod.cloudfire.it   172.20.15.35   80      170m
```

The namespace and the svc are correct and there's no typo. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong